# Deleting a non-toplevel item from a QTreeWidget

Tags: python, pyside, qtreewidget

In the documentation, I have seen that it is possible to delete top-level items from a QTreeWidget using `takeTopLevelItem()`. However, I need to delete items that are *not* top-level. I am completely lost on how to do this, so I'm resorting here for help. Any google searches I do end without proper results and the PySide docs are being thoroughly unhelpful. I suspect there is an easy way to do this and that I'm over-thinking it, but I have no clue how to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after thinking about it for 3 long days, I realized the answer *was*, as I suspected, rather simple (yet maybe a little convoluted).

I was trying to delete the item when the QTreeWidget was right clicked (just a little background so you understand my code).

```
tree = QTreeWidget()

def delItem(e):
    if e.reason() == QContextMenuEvent.Mouse:
        itemClicked = tree.itemAt(e.pos())
        for topItem in range(0,tree.topLevelItemCount()):
            topItem = tree.topLevelItem(topItem)
            if topItem.isSelected():
                tree.takeTopLevelItem(tree.indexOfTopLevelItem(topItem))
            else:
                def checkChildren(item):
                    if item.childCount() >= 0:
                        for childItem in range(0,item.childCount()):
                            childItem = item.child(childItem)
                            if childItem.isSelected():
                                item.removeChild(childItem)
                            else:
                                childItem.checkChildren()
                checkChildren(topItem)

tree.contextMenuEvent = delItem
```